# how to get class name by 'this'?also how to get attribute I defined?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function fn(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(obj.id);
    console.log(obj.did);
    console.log(obj.class);
    console.log("."+obj.class+"");
}
```

```html
<div id="id-content" did="did-content" class="class-content" onclick="fn(this)">
    innercontent
</div>
```

you might say I can get the class and customaed(?) attributes by jQuery,but here is a list of divs,I think I have to locate each attribute through 'this'(or any better recommendation?) 
so,I'm thinking use class name to get 'did' .help! XD

Comment: You need `obj.className`, but I don't think I understand what list of divs you're talking about. Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Use getAttribute to get the attribute of the element and use className instead of class:

```
function fn(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(obj.id);
    console.log(obj.getAttribute('did'));
    console.log(obj.className);
    console.log("."+obj.className+"");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct property is called **className**. Therefore. use `this.className`.

The reason for this is that the word "class" had dubious reserved word status in some version of JS. It will also likely be a reserved word in future versions of EcmaScript.

For other attributes, use `.getAttribute()`.

Comment: True but if you want the value of any attribute, I'd suggest using `getAttribute`, though. There are times when you will want to access properties, but properties of _HTMLElements_ aren't the same as _attributes_.